# Content of UITableViewCell gets clipped upon expanding the cell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to implement expandable cell with `UILabel` that would grow when user taps it. I set the constraint properly and modify the `numberOfLines` upon expanding so the size would be calculated correctly.
However, the cell grows in size properly but its content gets clipped off. When I start scrolling the content magically shows up. I have followed few tutorials and I have no idea where my mistake could lie. Please see the code below and GIF

Edit: Of course, I am returning the `UITableView.automaticDimension` as the height of the row

```
// Label configuration inside cell
    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        l.numberOfLines = 3
        l.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        return l
    }()

// Modifying this value should correctly resize the label
    var isExpanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            label.numberOfLines = isExpanded ? 0 : 3
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

// Setting up constraints. I'm using SnapKit for making the constraints
    func setupView() {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(15)
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(4).priority(.high)
        }
    }
```

And this is the code inside view controller that manages the tableView

```
func didChangeInfoExpanded(at path: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: path) as? InfoTableCell else {
            return
        }
        cell.isExpanded.toggle()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.transition(with: self.tableView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
             self.tableView.beginUpdates()
             self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }, completion: nil)
        
        /*
         I have also tried reloading the row but it's made a glitchy animation and the content was still clipped
         self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [path], with: .automatic)
         */
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's really difficult to tell from your animation what's what. Is that all one cell? And you want to expand / collapse the `UILabel`? Or are those multiple cells, and your expand/collapse cell has only the label in it?

Comment: It’s only one cell which is a custom UITableViewCell subclass and it’s called InfoTableCell. The path parameter in the method is the IndexPath of that cell. I want to expand to label, thus setting its numberOfLines to 0

Comment: What's triggering `didChangeInfoExpanded()`? Is that called when the cell is selected?

Comment: Yes, it’s called after tapping the cell

Comment: Hmmm... looking at your code, is there a specific reason you're using cross-dissolve transition in there?

Comment: It looks better than using begin/endupdates alone, but even if I don't use additional animations the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

A common issue is that when we set the number of lines from Zero to 3, the text of the label does not smoothly animate to 3 lines... it "snaps" to 3 lines, and then the bottom of the label frame, and the cell height, animates. Not a great visual effect.

Here's the best result I've gotten for this type of expand / collapse cell...

To the cell's `contentView` we add:

- `hiddenLabel` ... a `UILabel` that will be **hidden**
- `container` ... a `UIView` to hold the visible label

Then we add to the container view:

- `visibleLabel` ... a `UILabel`

Both labels get the same text.

We constrain the `hiddenLabel` to all 4 sides of the content view (using layout margins guide). When we change hiddenLabel's number of lines, that will determine the height of the cell.

We also constrain `container` to all 4 sides of the content view. When the content view changes height, that will change the height of the container.

Inside the container, we constrain `visibleLabel` ***only*** to Top / Leading / Trailing... so when it has number of lines set to Zero, it will extend outside the bounds of the container (but we won't see that, because container has `.clipsToBounds = true`).

This gives us a smooth expand/collapse animation, with the text in the label being "revealed" / "covered".

So, the cell class looks like this:

```
class ExpandCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let cellID: String = "expandCell"
    
    let container = UIView()
    let visibleLabel = UILabel()
    let hiddenLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        [hiddenLabel, visibleLabel, container].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(hiddenLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(container)
        container.addSubview(visibleLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain hiddenLabel Top / Leading / Trailing to contentView
            hiddenLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            hiddenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            hiddenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // use less than or equal for bottom constraint to avoid auto-layout warnings
            hiddenLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain container Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom to contentView
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain theLabel Top / Leading / Trailing to container
            visibleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            visibleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            visibleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // NO bottom constraint for theLabel
            
        ])
        
        // prevent theLabel from being visible outside the container
        container.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // label properties
        [hiddenLabel, visibleLabel].forEach {
            $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
            $0.numberOfLines = 3
            $0.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            $0.contentMode = .top
        }
        // hide the hidden label
        hiddenLabel.isHidden = true

        // during development, so we can easily see frames
        //visibleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
    }
    func setText(_ str: String, expanded: Bool) -> Void {
        hiddenLabel.text = str
        visibleLabel.text = str
        hiddenLabel.numberOfLines = expanded ? 0 : 3
        visibleLabel.numberOfLines = hiddenLabel.numberOfLines
    }
    func toggleExpanded() -> Bool {
        visibleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        hiddenLabel.numberOfLines = hiddenLabel.numberOfLines == 0 ? 3 : 0
        return hiddenLabel.numberOfLines == 0
    }
}
```

In `cellForRowAt` we set it up (for example):

```
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ExpandCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! ExpandCell
        // set both hidden and visible label text
        c.setText(detailString)
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
```

Then, in `didSelectRowAt` we can toggle the expanded / collapsed state with animation:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandCell {
        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            c.visibleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            c.toggleExpanded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            // we need to update the number of lines for the visible label
            //  so we get the ellipses when we're showing the collapsed state
            c.visibleLabel.numberOfLines = c.hiddenLabel.numberOfLines
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For now I'll just modify the `contentOffset` a bit to simulate scrolling, but I'm curious why that issue happens.

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
self.tableView.contentOffset.y += 0.2
```

`0.1` did not work, `0.2` was the smallest value that caused the content to appear. Hooray UIKit